# How can I repair my git configuration?

Tags: git, version-control, configuration

I ran `git config --global core.worktree` and it messed up all of my git repos. How can I undo this change? What's the default value for core.worktree and how can I set it up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply remove that config (`git config --global --unset core.worktree`)or:

> Set the path to the root of the working tree.
>   This can be overridden by the `GIT_WORK_TREE` environment variable and the `--work-tree` command line option

The default work_tree directory is the one with the `.git` in it.